# Unable to initialize private const member

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, constants

I want to have an `int` associated with my class that is set when the user of this class instantiates it.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int x);
private:
  const int x;
};
```

To initialize this constant, I try to use the contructor (Java style):

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x) {
  this->x = x;
}
```

However, my compiler doesn't quite like it this way, and I get the following:

```
const.cxx: In constructor ‘MyClass::MyClass(int)’:
const.cxx:3:1: error: uninitialized const member in ‘const int’ [-fpermissive]
 MyClass::MyClass(int x) {
 ^
In file included from const.cxx:1:0:
const.h:8:13: note: ‘const int MyClass::x’ should be initialized
   const int x;
             ^
const.cxx:4:11: error: assignment of read-only member ‘MyClass::x’
   this->x = x;
           ^
```

What is the C++ way to initialize an instantiated constant based on the constructor a la Java?

EDIT: I saw the question marked as duplicate; that thread failed to mention you could use the constructor's parameters in the initializer list, since it only use numeric literals in all the examples.

Comment: Use an [initialiser list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list): `MyClass::MyClass(int x) : x(x) {}`

Comment: And BTW, use that for non-const members too...

Comment: Use _initialization_, not assignment.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question. The other question asks about initialising a `const int` in the declaration of the class, whereas this is asking about passing a parameter to initialise it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use what's called an initializer list in the constructor's function signature:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x) : x(x) {
}
```